# Why am I unable to authenticate my app against DocuSign?

Tags: api, authentication, docusignapi

I have created an app in DocuSign and am following the instructions to get it set up [here](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-please-mr-postman). I have created the integration key and secret key, and set my redirect uri to "http://localhost"

However, when I attempt to substitute these values into the url below, I only get an error

[https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id={iKey}&redirect_uri={callback}](https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=%7BiKey%7D&redirect_uri=%7Bcallback%7D)

Here is a screenshot of the error I receive[image]

As far as I can tell, these instructions simply don't work. Is there any alternative documentation for authenticating an app in DocuSign? Or is there something I am missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I found a video that answered my question. The URL in the {callback} value needs to include the "http://" in order to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
redirect_uri={callback}
```

replace {callback} with some URL you want to be redirected with.

Then, go to the [Apps and Keys page](https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=appsAndKeys) and find your IK and configure it by adding this URL in the list.

Wait 30 seconds
try again (make sure you updated your URL correctly)

Comment: Thank you for that. I forgot to provide my example URL, which looks like this

https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=3e955b6e-66a8-4aeb-b85a-dfcdf6ec52cd&redirect_uri=localhost

In other words, I do not have a URL handy to use, so I used localhost, as suggested by the documentation.

Comment: you can use localhost, but you have to update your IK to include the exact URL you use

Comment: That seems awfully circular, but I will try it. I set my redirect URI to:

http://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature&client_id=3e955b6e-66a8-4aeb-b85a-dfcdf6ec52cd&redirect_uri=localhost

But I am still getting the same error

Comment: You need to set it to localhost. not sure you want http or https to be added

Comment: You just told me to update the redirect URI in the IK to match the URL I am using...

Comment: Nevermind. I found a video that answered my question. The URL needs to include the "http://" in order to work.